# Utility to view threads in a Java process

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I've got a java application on a windows machine which pins the CPU from time to time.  Would like to run a utility to get an idea of how many threads etc that application is creating.  Is there such a utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always been partial to [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/).

There are lots of others though, both open source and commercial.  If you do a google search for "[java profilers](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+profilers)" you should be able to find one to your liking.

Answer (score 10):

[jconsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) is included with the jdk and includes thread/memory/cpu monitoring

Answer (score 5):

You could try [jstack](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), should be part of the jdk.

Answer (score 4):

get a look at `jvisualvm` (in the jdk)

Comment: this is only present until java 8. it has been removed after